# How to find the most similar array base on value's weight?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, filtering

I have an object with given user.

```
const user = [{ id: '1', city: 'Paris', cuisine: 'italian', allergic: 'no', budget: '50', hasChildren: 'yes' }]
```

And an array of objects with restaurants. I want to find this user a restaurant that matches his requirements the most.

```
const restaurants: [
 {
  cuisine: 'mexican',
  averageCost: '30',
  children: 'no'
 },
 {
  cuisine: 'italian',
  averageCost: '30',
  children: 'yes'
 }
]
```

So the second restaurant is more suitable for the user, so it should appear as first one. Every key should has some weight, because e.g. cuisine is more important than cost, so it should have bigger score. How can I achieve it? Is there any algorithm that do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you just looking for the closest fit in terms of cost/cuisine? If so, you'd have to give a weight to cuisines so that it can essentially be normalized into cost differences, then you could sort by the overall suitability of a match (in this case suitability would be closest in cost and cuisine preference)

Comment: Please show your attempt and explain where you're stuck.  This is a straightforward sorting algorithm, but you've failed to provide the sort key: your evaluation function.  We can't decide that for you.  The weights and interactions of factors are still inside your head, or await you to research the effect you want from something complex.  Until you've defined that, we can't even place you into the proper paradigm: optimization with constraints, straight linear evaluation, or some sort of deep learning model.

Answer (score 1):

I have given a simple implementation below. The idea is to create a `scoring function` for your restaurants that depends on the `user data` and the `restaurant data.` Then sort your restaurants using that function as scoring for the restaurant. Score descendent to get the most "closest" restaurants on the top.

You can assign weights to the scores as you please.

```
// Given
const restaurants = [
 {
  cuisine: 'mexican',
  averageCost: '30',
  children: 'no'
 },
 {
  cuisine: 'italian',
  averageCost: '30',
  children: 'yes'
 }
];

const user = [{ id: '1', city: 'Paris', cuisine: 'italian', allergic: 'no', budget: '50', hasChildren: 'yes' }];


const calculateScore = (user, restaurant) => {
    // you can fine tune the values for the weights yourself

    // asume that children score gives 1
    const childrenScore = (user.hasChildren === restaurant.children) ? 1 : 0;

    // asume that cuisine score gives 1
    const cuisineScore = (user.cuisine === restaurant.cuisine) ? 1 : 0;

    // asume that cost score gives the absolute difference
    const costScore = Math.abs(parseInt(restaurant.averageCost) - parseInt(user.budget));

    return childrenScore + cuisineScore + costScore;
}

const sortedRestaurants = restaurants.sort((rA, rB) => {
    const rAScore = calculateScore(user[0], rA);
    const rBScore = calculateScore(user[0], rB);
    return rBScore - rAScore; // sort DESC by score
});

console.log(sortedRestaurants)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet of something you could do.

```js
const user = [{ id: '1', city: 'Paris', cuisine: 'italian', allergic: 'no', budget: '50', hasChildren: 'yes' }];
const restaurants = [
    {
     cuisine: 'mexican',
     averageCost: '30',
     children: 'no'
    },
    {
     cuisine: 'italian',
     averageCost: '30',
     children: 'yes'
    }
]

const orderedRestaurants = restaurants.map(r => {
    return {
        ...r,
        score: 0 +
        (r.cuisine === user[0].cuisine ? 4 : 0) +
        (r.averageCost <= user[0].budget ? 8 : 0) +
        (r.children === 'no' && user[0].hasChildren === 'yes' ? 0 : 3)
    }
}).sort((a,b) => b.score - a.score);

console.log(orderedRestaurants);
```

So we need to assign each restaurant a score based on certain criteria. I've assigned the weights in the function, you could possibly move that outside into an object for dynamic scoring.

In this example, we're giving them 4 points if the cuisine matches the user's interest, assigning 8 points if the average cost is less than or equal to the budget, and assigning 3 points if the user has kids and the restaurant allows children. Feel free to edit the scoring system as you please, but hopefully this can get you started.